# Issue with a login&register system. Receiving and error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I've searched this issue high and low. I've also seen it asked in many places but never to the point in which i am having the issue. Nor I have found a solution that has fixed mine. I've spent a very long time trying to fix this and I can not move forward until it has been resolved any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

It's a login & register tutorial by phpacademy.

My error is as follows:

Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\core\functions\users.php on line 5

The code I have for my users.php file is as follows and is 100% the same as is on the tutorial. Mine fails to work his does not.

```
<?php
function user_exists ($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

The following is line 5 from the above code where the error appears to be resulting from.

```
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
```

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Find out any mysql error you might get by doing `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: How would one go about doing this, sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize :), after `$query = mysql_query(...)` call `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: I get this error. Table 'login.users' doesn't exist

Comment: 'users' should have been 'user'. Doh. thanks =)

Comment: There we go :D, glad to be of help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that your previous statement `mysql_query`

```
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
```

has returned false, if you check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) it states that on failure `mysql_query` will return false. Therefore we need to come to a conclusion that your query is failing. To find out more information on why your query is failing. Include `mysql_error()` at the end of the statement.

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I get the following error after appending on the error request.                Table 'login.users' doesn't exist